# how to access an instance of a class from its instance variable

Tags: java, instance-variables

So I have this scenario

class A:

```
public class A {
    B b = new B();

    public void doSomething() {
         // this does something
    }
}
```

and class B:

```
public class B {
    public B() {
       // need to access A
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to access the instance of A from the A's instance variable B. How do I do that?

Comment: You have to store a reference to the A instance in the B instance when you create it.  (Or make B an inner class to A, which is the same difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply pass the instance of `A` to `B`:

```
class A {
  B b;
  A() {
    b = new B(this);//<-- A's instance
  }
}

class B {
  A a;
  B(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it to work now, I would up vote this answer but I'm not allowed to do that... To anyone else, the above code works

Comment: @Totalllyrandomguy, you can accept the answer by selecting the check mark just below the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If class `B`needs to access an existing instance of `A` then you must provide the `B` instance with a reference to the `A` instance.

```
class B {
    private A a;
    B(A a) { 
        this.a = a; 
        // do something with a 
    }
}
```

then

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
```

If you need access to the `A` only within the constructor then you don't need to store a local copy of the reference.

Answer (score -1):

You must create new object from instance A

```
A aa = new A();
```

OR

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
       // need to access A
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not what I mean, I don't want B to extend A because it they have different functionalities, for example A is a JPanel and B is a JButton, or something like that. but I want the button to do something the Panel.

Comment: You must create new object in class B  A aa = new A(); and you can called  aa.doSomeThing();

Comment: @SardorDushamov I think you have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -1):

Inner Class seems like the best thing to do ,

```
  public class A {
        B b = new B();
        private int tryToAccess;
        public void doSomething() {
             // this does something
        }

    public class B{

     public B()
         {
          tryToAccess=5;
         }
    }//B ends
   }//A ends
```

**Note**:*This is just one way of going about it , here you can access `A`'s `private` variables from `class` `B`*

Comment: is there a way to do it without using an inner class? Classes A and B will each be used separately by other classes at some point, its just that Class and has an instance of B as a variable and b needs to access the instance of A that it is in.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't and I can't thing of any practical situation where you need to do so ,most such problems are solved using inner classes,still the best you can do is write a method in B which take object A as an argument and try something like this ,A a=new A(),         a.b.access(a);